# linking to the product from the index in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

When I save a PayerContract in the create form, it saves the PayerContract and creates a "success you have created PayerContract {X}" where {X} is the PayerContract name and redirects the user back to the index. I want to allow the user to click the {X} to go to the edit page for that PayerContract.

In my index page I have:

```
  = link_to t('payer_contracts.edit'), edit_payer_contract_path())
```

I need to give the PayerContract.id to the edit_payer_contract_path function. So, it would look something like `edit_payer_contract_path(330)`

The warning message I have displayed in my controller is this:

```
def create
    payer_contract_params = PayerContract.assign_params_to_payer_contract(params)
    @payer_contract = PayerContract.new(payer_contract_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        if @payer_contract.save
          format.html { redirect_to payer_contracts_path, notice: t('common.successfully_created', entity: @payer_contract.description) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

I found out that when I do something like:
`edit_payer_contract_path(PayerContract.find())` it returns all the PayerContract that looks like: expected an attributes Hash, got `[{"id"=>224, "name" ="hello", "id"=> 332, "name" = "hello2", "id"=>555, "name" = "sup" }]` etc.

How can I correctly link the user to the PayerContract they just created?

Answer (score 0):

you can have it two ways. Either pass parameter along your `redirect_to` method. obviously, pass the id of newly created PayerContract. This way you will have the id in `params` and you can use it in your `link_to` method.

If you don't want to pass the parameter, try storing the newly created PayerContract in session after successfully creating PayerContract. This way after redirect you will still have access to the saved value from the session
something like below

```
def create
  @foo = Foo.new(foo_params)
  if foo.save
    session[:foo_id] = @foo.id
    redirect_to foo_path
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

As beniutek said you can pass parameter in redirect_to. But when user first visit index page id is not defined so you can check in view if it is define set the id to link_to as below.

```
def create
    payer_contract_params = PayerContract.assign_params_to_payer_contract(params)
    @payer_contract = PayerContract.new(payer_contract_params)
    respond_to do |format|
      begin
        if @payer_contract.save
          format.html { redirect_to payer_contracts_path(id: @payer_contract.id), notice: t('common.successfully_created', entity: @payer_contract.description) }
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

In view

```
 if params[:id].present? 
     = link_to t('payer_contracts.edit'), edit_payer_contract_path(params[:id].to_i))
```

Comment: It still can't find id for the edit_payer_contract_path. Any idea?

Comment: Hello John please see the updated answer. you need to set params id as  edit_payer_contract_path(params[:id].to_i)

Comment: Also passing params in t() will not send to your index page. you need to payer_contracts_path(id: @payer_contract.id). I hope updated answer should solve this..